# SSRS 2008 Format a cell to blank if value is 0 or null or anything other than a number

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a cell expression in which Im trying to force it to simply display an empty cell if the underlying value is something other than a number, is zero or null etc.  There is no formatting in the textbox properties.

Surely there is something simpler

What I have now

```
        =IIF(IsDBNull(ReportItems!YE_Goal2.Value) OR  
    ReportItems!YE_Goal2.Value = 0 OR  ReportItems!YE_Goal2.Value Is Nothing, 
"",ReportItems!Projected2.Value/ReportItems!YE_Goal2.Value)
```

When there is no value, it displays a 0 instead of being blank.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=IIf(
  Not IsNumeric(ReportItems!YE_Goal2.Value) or
  IsNothing(ReportItems!YE_Goal2.Value) or
  ReportItems!YE_Goal2.Value=0, "",ReportItems!Projected2.Value/
     iif(ReportItems!YE_Goal2.Value=0,1,ReportItems!YE_Goal2.Value)
)
```

Note you have to validate two times `ReportItems!YE_Goal2.Value=0`, First time for control flow, the second time in order to avoid validator throw erros for division by zero.